# Ignite Hibernate 5 Compatible version

Tags: java, hibernate, ignite

I am trying to use ignite along with my Spring Boot & hibernate application. Which version of ignite is compatible with Hibernate 5?

Also, How do I install ignite-hibernate dependencies to my local maven repo?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 5 support should be added in Apache Ignite 2.0.
There is a ticket [1] that already resolved and merged to master.

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-1794

Comment: How do we use ignite meanwhile??

Comment: How do you use Ignite?